# equivalent of #define in XML?

Tags: xml, reference, dtd

Can I define "20" in the below example in a separate file to which I can refer to, similar to #define in C/C++? If not, is there any way to achieve the desired effect?

```
<p>The width should be 20 cm</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, it's called an "external entity".

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no" ?>
<!DOCTYPE p [
  <!ELEMENT p (#PCDATA)>
  <!ENTITY width SYSTEM "width.xml">
]>
<p>The width should be &width; cm</p>
```

width.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no" ?>
20
```

Personally, though, I don't like this mechanism, because it's not flexible enough. Usually I'm processing my XML through an XSLT stylesheet, and then I find it more convenient to use processing instructions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no" ?>
<p>The width should be <?width?> cm</p>
```

with the stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet ....>

<xsl:param name="width"/>

<xsl:template match="processing-instruction('width')">
  <xsl:value-of select="$width"/>
</xsl:template>
```

The XSLT approach makes it much easier to supply the value of width as a parameter from your application.